# AngularJS ng-repeat <table> with pagination

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using angularJS to render a table with pagination, 
below is working fiddle with pagination i found in internet:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/9086/
```

now i have forked the fiddle as given below:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/w6egw14b/2/
```

i have removed the below function and given the same in ng-click,

```
$scope.setPage = function() {
    $scope.currentPage = this.n;
};
```

but it is not working when i click on page numbers, can anyone tell me why it is failing? how can i achieve this?

my goal is to make these functions work individually with many tables that are present in same page,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a classic scope problem.
Your

```
<li ng-repeat="n in range(pagedItems.length, currentPage, currentPage + gap) " ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}" ng-click="currentPage = n;">
  <a href ng-bind="n + 1">1</a>
</li>
```

create its own scope and setting currentPage will create a variable in this new scope, not the controller's scope.

Simple and dirty solution :

```
<li ng-repeat="n in range(pagedItems.length, currentPage, currentPage + gap) " ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}" ng-click="$parent.currentPage = n;">
  <a href ng-bind="n + 1">1</a>
</li>
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtassin/w6egw14b/5/)

I think that you should definitely keep the setPage function (or even better, pass to a named controller).